# Are arm-triangle chokes legal in Judo?

Tags: judo, sport, chokes, pins

When holding an opponent in [kata-gatame](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kata_gatame):

[image]

by applying pressure to one side of their neck with their trapped shoulder, and the other side with your enclosed arms, you can apply an [arm triangle choke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arm_triangle_choke), mechanically similar to sankaku-jime, but utilising your arms instead of your legs.

Is this submission legal in judo randori/competition?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, arm triangles are legal provided you trap one of uke's arms with their head. According to the [IJF Refereeing Seminar 2018](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tHM_5SThkBM):

> An action like kata-sankaku (sankaku done with the arms) is allowed in a newaza situation.

Here are some examples of its use in international competition:

- World U21 Championships 2015 ([Jorre Verstraeten](https://www.judoinside.com/judovideo/35138/Jorre_VERSTRAETEN_BEL_Ahmed_ELFIKY_EGY_U55_World_U21_Championships_Abu_Dhabi_2015))
- Jigoro Kano Cup Tokyo 2007 ([Masahiko Tomouchi](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=poAK4iFBMjQ))
- World Championships 2007 ([Matthieu Bataille](https://www.judoinside.com/judovideo/522/Matthieu_BATAILLE_FRA_Daniel_Andrey_HERNANDES_BRA_World_Championships_Rio_de_Janeiro_2007))
- Pan American Championships 2000 ([Katherine Ensler](https://www.judoinside.com/news/1473/Report_of_the_Pan_American_Judo_Championships_2000_in_Orlando_Day_2))
- Grand Prix 2013 ([Sally Conway](https://www.judoinside.com/judovideo/14243/Assmaa_NIANG_MAR_Sally_CONWAY_GBR_Grand_Prix_Samsun_2013))
- Grand Prix 2017 ([Andrey Volkov](https://www.judoinside.com/judovideo/54133/Andrey_VOLKOV_RUS_Anton_KRIVOBOKOV_RUS_O100_Grand_Prix_Hohhot_2017))

And here it is being demonstrated in various seminars:

- [George Ku](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eBkS5OI7Css) (8th dan)
- [Steve Scott](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gbdG4cbZenk) (8th dan)
- [Adam Hall](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pLvUBJJHRWM)
- [Kyuzo Mifune](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FlSmenjni7o) demonstrating it in "The Essence of Judo".

Comment: @ukemi I don't understand why there is more concern with the jaw from this versus the leg sankaku or other chokes. The obvious advantage of this choke is that the osaekomi pin clock is running even if the choke is not successful.

Answer (score 3):

Just to add to mattm's answer - the IJF has now codified its position in the [current ruleset](https://www.ijf.org/ijf/documents/5):

[image: "The kata-sankaku grip in ne-waza action is allowed (picture 1). It is prohibited to block the opponents body with the legs and must be mate (picture 2). If the katasankaku grip is used in tachi-waza mate will be called (picture 3)."]

So in short, the following submissions are/aren't legal:

| Technique | Legal |
| --- | --- |
| Anaconda | ✅ |
| Kata-gatame | ✅ |
| D'arce<sup>1</sup> | ✅ |
| Peruvian necktie | ✅ |
| Arm triangle from closed guard | ❌ |
| Standing arm triangles | ❌ |

---

1. AKA Ungvari / Brabo choke / Japanese necktie