# Is the "Peruvian Necktie" legal in Judo?

Tags: judo, brazilian-jiu-jitsu, sport, chokes

"Peruvian Necktie" refers to an arm triangle choke from the sprawl position, with one leg over uke's head and the other over their back:<sup>1</sup>

[image]

[The IJF rules](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/a/9756/8910) ban arm-triangles which "block the opponent's body with the legs", and alhough the example picture<sup>2</sup> for this rule shows a do-jime/closed guard position (as opposed to the Peruvian necktie 'side-on' position), the wording is a big vague.

**Is the Peruvian necktie competition legal?**

---

1. This term is also sometimes used to refer to the ["Gerbi" choke](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/9759/is-the-gerbi-choke-legal-using-your-opponents-jacket), a similar choke applied with tori's gi-skirt.
2. > [image]
   >
   > Kata-sankaku grip situation in ne-waza: it is prohibited to block the opponent's body with the legs and mate must be announced (picture 2).

Comment: A question I have on this technique is how dangerous can it be if the practitioner is looking to harm the opponent.  (It looks like it could be used to break the neck—pretty sure I've even seen forms of that in MMA fight choreography since maybe as far back as *Sha Po Lang*.)

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/judo/comments/vwwc82/the_ijf_hamstrings_the_growth_of_judo_peruvian/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The kata-sankaku prohibition is about danger to the neck joints in my understanding. In the guillotine position (your footnote #2 with the yellow background), you threaten the neck joints, while you can apply the Peruvian necktie variant without threatening the neck joints even while blocking with the legs. As long as you do not crank the neck down, I expect this is legal.

The Peruvian necktie may refer to variants that straddle the judo rules; some may be legal while others are not. The Gerbi choke runs afoul of the rule against using the jacket skirt or belt as a garrote (rule is not in those exact words).

Answer (score 2):

It appears this version is considered valid, and has been used multiple times at high level competition:

[image]

- [Agbegnenou vs Vermeer | -63kg | World Championships 2021](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_ab2GqDeKJU&t=210s) (3:30)
- [Van T End vs Gviniashvili | -90kg | Doha Masters 2021](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zSSfFu-Fx60&t=400s) (6:40)